# Use NTLM authentication with Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a WebApi that uses NTLM authentication and I am trying to write a simple React UI to get data from the API but getting 401.

`axios.get('url').then(response => console.log(response));`

How can I pass my Windows credentials along with the get request?

Thanks

Comment: did u ever get this working?

Comment: No. Using fetch where the credentials can be passed.

Comment: Do you use IE? Or Chrome? I have a similar problem, the auth works only in IE :(

Comment: My app does not work with IE. It is an intranet app. It runs on Chrome, Firefox etc, with Fetch instead of Axios

Comment: i'm stuck in the same problem right now and it's almost making me pull my hair out :) but not using react. I will update you if I find the fix

Comment: I would also like to find the answer.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I got it to work with postman but I had to enter my windows credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Axios provides a withCredentials property on request. This is false by default, set it to true and you should be good to go.

```
Axios.get('url', {
withCredentials: true } )
```

Comment: This does work for GET, but not for PUT. Oddly i get errors using the same strategy for PUT.

I get preflight errors (CORS) and net::ERR_FAILED

Anyone seen a case where GET works, but PUT fails?

Comment: @user5855178 I know it's probably a bit late for an answer, but most likely what's happening is that your server is blocking OPTIONS requests.  We ran into this using an ASP.net core API with Vue.  When you do a PUT request, an OPTIONS request happens first.  The problem is that there are no auth headers sent with OPTIONS requests and so the asp.net app will block it. I had to create a custom Web.config that would specifically allow all OPTIONS requests through unauthenticated.